# PHP cURL does not send appropriate headers

Tags: php, curl, header

I'm trying to send some headers with cURL in PHP and the headers are not sending.

The code is:

```
$header = array('Referer: xxx',
        'Origin: xxx',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
        'Except:');
```

and using this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$t = curl_exec($ch);

$sentHeaders = curl_getinfo($ch);

var_dump($sentHeaders);
```

and in the dump I didn't see Origin, content-type, referrer and nothing... I'm trying to send a POST and it isn't sending.

What I am doing wrong?

edited:
Now POST isn't sending:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$t = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: What means *im trying to send POST and nothing too*? what shows `curl_error($ch);`, whats the `$t` content after the request? How do you know POST is not working?

Comment: curl_error is empty, in $t i have a form, demostrating post isn't send (sorry for the english)

Comment: Use brower addon like HttpFox to find out the difference with your request through curl and the one you browser does.

Answer (score 1):

Add this option to see the request headers in the `getinfo` call:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

Comment: ooh thank you! now i see, but the post isn't working and didn't know why, edited code with post functions

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your POST problem: 
be sure to use `http_build_query()`. So it needs to be in your code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data) );
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Wrong. You can pass an array directly